# Download files from clearcase dynamic view

Tags: java, shell, clearcase

i have a requirement,here i need to download some files from clearcase dynamic view  to local machine programatically, so what is the possible ways we can use in that.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a snapshot view, with:

- the same config spec than the dynamic view
- load rules which would load only the subset of files you want.

That way, programmatically, you can simply "cleartool update" that snapshot view and it will update only those files.

---

If you want to use only the dynamic view, then you would need to write a script which would copy the files from the view (`M:\yourDynView\YourVobs\...` or `/view/YourDynView/vobs/YourVob/...`) to your drive.